# I want to print the line in my textfile that starts with a specific license number, but this only prints out if the license number is in the 1st line

Tags: python

I want to be able to print every line in my textfile that starts with a specific car license number, but my function only prints out the license number I want  if the license number is in the first line

```
with open("data","r") as file:
    for line in file:
        file.readlines()
        which_car = input("Please write your license number: ")
        if not line.startswith(which_car):
            print("Please write the license number an existing car! ")
            history()
        else:
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must put the which_car outside the loop. Also, from my understanding, you want to print all lines that begin with the number provided and if there is no line that begins with that number, then only in that case you will print the alternative message. If this is what you want, try the following. You would better add it in a function, so that it will run every time user inputs a new licence number:

```
with open("data","r") as file:
    rows=file.readlines()
    which_car = input("Please write your license number: ")
    c=0
    for line in rows:
        if line.startswith(which_car):
            print(line)
            c+=1
    if c==0:
        print("Please write the license number of an existing car! ")
        history()
```

Version 2: Using a function:

```
def check_licence_number():
    which_car = input("Please write your license number: ")
    c=0
    with open("data","r") as file:
        rows=file.readlines()
        for line in rows:
            if line.startswith(which_car):
                print(line)
                c+=1
        if c==0:
            print("Please write the license number of an existing car!")
            check_licence_number()
```

Comment: Oh this works great! I just wonder what the point with c is? I dont understand how it helped me

Comment: We use c to check if there is no line that starts with the licence number. If this happens, c will be 0, otherwise it will be non zero and this part of the code will not run. We need it to be checked ony after all lines are checked, at the end of the loop

Comment: Thank you! I understand now.

Comment: I did a small change, so that c will work properly now (increased by 1 when a line starts with licence number)

Answer (score 0):

Your original code didn't work because your `for line in file:` loop executes `rows = file.readlines()` in the first line of the loop. With `readlines` you read everything in the file, so the `for` loop won't repeat because there is nothing more to read. Use either the `for` loop or `readlines`. In this case you should prefer the `for` loop because it iterates over the file and there is no need to have the full content of the file in memory.

I assume that your code is in a function called `history` and you tried to call it again if no match was found. That's not a good approach (I'd even say it's a pretty bad approach) because you get recursive calls.

If you want to ask the user for a license number until it could be found you should use a `while True` loop. This loop repeats forever until you do a `break`.

Here we loop over all lines in the file and print lines that match. If a match is found we set the flag `found` to `True`. When the loop over the file is finished we check this flag and break out of the outer while loop. If we don't find a match the program will ask for a new license number.

```
while True:
    which_car = input("Please write your license number: ")
    found = False
    with open("data", "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            if line.startswith(which_car):
                found = True
                print(line)
    if found:
        break
    print("Please write the license number of an existing car! ")
```

If you expect the user to enter a wrong license plate most of the time, then `readlines` might be an alternative. In that case you should read the file before the loop starts, so you don't have to do it every time.

```
with open("data", "r") as file:
    license_numbers = file.readlines()
while True:
    which_car = input("Please write your license number: ")
    found = False
    for line in license_numbers:
        if line.startswith(which_car):
            found = True
            print(line)
    if found:
        break
    print("Please write the license number of an existing car! ")
```